# script locating too many classes

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

screenshot: https://gyazo.com/b36f58b8f066bd84f3d1bf941b9e3e31 - pay extra attention to the pycharm output, it shows 4 results. But when i ctrl + f in html source. There is only 3.   How does this make sence?
input:

```
an = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#content > div.sidebar-layout > section > table > tbody > .dbaListing.listing.hasInsertionFee')


for i in an:
    print(i, '\n')
```

output:  (I get 4 for some reason? Which wasnt expected..)

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b0cda760-ce1d-11e6-8eeb-879135080997", element=":wdc:1483053765956")> 

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b0cda760-ce1d-11e6-8eeb-879135080997", element=":wdc:1483053765957")> 

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b0cda760-ce1d-11e6-8eeb-879135080997", element=":wdc:1483053765958")> 

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b0cda760-ce1d-11e6-8eeb-879135080997", element=":wdc:1483053765959")>
```

My code should figure out how many ".dbaListing.listing.hasInsertionFee" there is in the html. It not that important why I want this. But for some reason (please take a quick a look at the screenshot pay attention to the ".dbaListing.listing.hasInsertionFee") for some reason I get 4 in out all the time. It keeps finding 4, even though there clearly only is 3!

I have checked manually in the html, there is only 3, if someone could come with an explanation to this, and maybe a fix. That would be great.

The html of the page:  (ctrl + f, and then search for "dbalisting listing hasinsertionfee" to find the place)

```
    dataLayer.push(dbaContext);
</script><style type="text/css">:root DIV[id^="google-dfp-skyscraper"],
:root .gcsa,
:root .marketing-container,
:root .dbaListing.listing.cpcListing,
:root .banner.megaboard,
:root .banner.calculation-banners.clearfix,
:root .topBannerWrapper.expandableTopBannerWrapper,
:root .sekBannerTop.fixIeBox,
:root .banner.takeover.original,
:root .adslot.adslot-megaboard,
:root .adslot,
:root #content > #right > .dose > .dosesingle,
:root #content > #center > .dose > .dosesingle,
:root .placeholderAd,
:root .plainAd,
:root .player_ad,
:root .playerAd,
:root .player_page_ad_box,
:root .player_hover_ad,
:root .player-ads,
:root .playAds2,
:root .player_ad_box,
:root .player_ad2,
:root .placeholder-ad,
:root .ad-space,
:root .play-page-ads,
:root .player-under-ad
{display:none !important;}</style><style>img[src="//ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/ad/vgs63pq/58v/1gc2/v2h1wao/pt7xb/;ord=1483043976758?"],
img[src="//0914.global.ssl.fastly.net/ad/img/x.gif?cb=1483043976792"],
img[src="//ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/ad/2kmg/9qv2u6b/tsmv6dq/pdd0m/;ord=1483043977288?"],
img[src="//0914.global.ssl.fastly.net/ad/img/x.gif?cb=1483043977323"],
img[src="//0914.global.ssl.fastly.net/ad/img/x.gif?cb=1483043981280"],
img[src="//ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/ad/457w1/5x7ipeg/vla3btcb8k/;ord=1483043981282?"],
img[src="//0914.global.ssl.fastly.net/ad/img/x.gif?cb=1483043981284"],
img[src="//ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/ad/y32/q3dhh060e80w/;ord=1483043981285?"],
img[src="//ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/ad/3ov7/vlgiif2zjoc/g4hbi/4hcbxyr5rj4/;ord=1483043981913?"],
img[src="//0914.global.ssl.fastly.net/ad/img/x.gif?cb=1483043982024"],
img[src="//ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/ad/yqaif2r05c0w/d47sp1la9/iduo928lyk/;ord=1483043982449?"],
img[src="//0914.global.ssl.fastly.net/ad/img/x.gif?cb=1483043982544"],
img[src="//0914.global.ssl.fastly.net/ad/img/x.gif?cb=1483044011180"],
img[src="//ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/ad/tb1/9yfjk9xuf40/;ord=1483044011181?"],
img[src="//0914.global.ssl.fastly.net/ad/img/x.gif?cb=1483044011183"],
img[src="//ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/ad/tyn7qd/699spki1/;ord=1483044011183?"],
img[src="//ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/ad/8c1m702m2g/umihf/kk83i2ihh4/47m8/;ord=1483044014540?"],
img[src="//0914.global.ssl.fastly.net/ad/img/x.gif?cb=1483044014574"],
img[src="//ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/ad/clf514fcx/2a89pt/;ord=1483044015056?"],
img[src="//0914.global.ssl.fastly.net/ad/img/x.gif?cb=1483044015099"]
{display:none !important;}</style>



    <script src="http://dbastatic.dk/Content/scripts/lib/modernizr.custom.js?2.0.0.0-648b216" charset="utf-8"></script>


        <script src="http://dbastatic.dk/RequestReduceContent/a6707d2f967132894f56933b0362b159-aa81bb596e42a9896f0a42315fcc739c-RequestReducedScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css" id="qual_style-fp"></style><style type="text/css" id="qual_style-fq"></style></head>
<body class="fixed">
<script data-script="TagManagerScript">
    (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({ 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src = '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XS9J');
</script>





<div id="page">




<header id="defaultHeader">
    <div class="container">
        <b class="logo"><a href="http://www.dba.dk" title="Nyt og brugt, køb og salg på DBA - Danmarks største handelsportal">Køb og sælg både nye og brugte nye varer på DBA – du finder over 1 mio. billige ting til salg.</a></b>
        <nav class="nav-top">
            <ul class="unstyled">


    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" data-bind="foreach: items">
        <li data-bind="css: {read: Read}" class="">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="http://www.dba.dk/produkt-tilvalg/?id=1029751995&amp;produktId=1" data-bind="attr: {href: Url, 'data-ga-lbl': $parent.itemLabel($data)}" class="trackClicks" data-ga-act="NotificationInboxItemClick" data-ga-lbl="upsell-unread">
                <i class="svg-icon-14 svg-upsell" data-bind="css: $parent.icon(Type)"></i> <small class="muted when" data-bind="text: TimeText">20. december</small>  <span data-bind="text: Text">Din annonce 'Tastatur, Mad Catz, Strike 7' er på side 32. Kom øverst i rubrikken.</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider" data-bind="visible: $parent.showDivider($index)" style="display: none;"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</li>
                <li><a href="https://guide.dba.dk" target="_blank" data-ga-act="dba-blog" data-ga-lbl="header" class="trackClicks">DBA Guide</a></li>

                <li><a href="http://www.dba.dk/aspsite/support/" data-ga-act="hjaelp" data-ga-lbl="header" class="trackClicks">Hjælp</a></li>


                    <button class="btn btn-large btn-search" type="submit"><span class="icon"></span>Søg</button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-bind="template {name: template(), foreach: dropdown}, css: {latest: template() === 'latest'}"></ul>
    <script type="text/template" id="latest">
                <li data-bind="css: {disabled: IsEmpty}">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="attr: {href: Url, 'data-ga-lbl': 'link-' + ($index() + 1) }" class="trackClicks" data-ga-act="recent-search-query-clicked">
                        <small class="badge pull-right" data-bind="text: Results"></small>
                        <span data-bind="text: Query"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
    </script>
    <script type="text/template" id="predictive">
        <li>
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="attr: {href: Url, 'data-ga-lbl': 'link-' + ($index() + 1) }" class="trackClicks" data-ga-act="predictive-search-clicked">
                <small class="badge pull-right" data-bind="text: Hits"></small>
                <strong data-bind="text: Name"></strong>
                <small class="sub-text muted" data-bind="text: PlacementDisplayText"></small>
            </a>
        </li>
    </script>

                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="header-actions">
                <div id="mydba-menu" class="dropdown-header pull-right">

                    <div class="btn-group"><a href="/min-dbadk/" data-ga-act="min-dba" data-ga-lbl="header" class="btn btn-large btn-menu trackClicks">Min DBA</a>    <button class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-large btn-menu" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="/min-dbadk/mine-annoncer/" data-ga-act="mine-annoncer" data-ga-lbl="header" class="trackClicks">Mine annoncer<span data-bind="{text:QuestionsAndAnswersCounts().SumNewListingPostCountOwnListings, visible: QuestionsAndAnswersCounts().SumNewListingPostCountOwnListings > 0 }" title="Der er nye indlæg i Spørgsmål og svar" class="badge badge-important" style="display:none">0</span></a></li><li><a href="/min-dbadk/favoritter/" data-ga-act="gemte-annoncer" data-ga-lbl="header" class="trackClicks">Favoritter<span data-bind="{text:QuestionsAndAnswersCounts().SumNewListingPostCountOtherListings, visible: QuestionsAndAnswersCounts().SumNewListingPostCountOtherListings > 0 }" title="Der er nye indlæg i Spørgsmål og svar" class="badge badge-important" style="display:none">0</span></a></li>        <li><a href="/min-dbadk/saelgere-jeg-foelger/" data-ga-act="navigate-to-followee-list" data-ga-lbl="social" class="trackClicks">Sælgere du følger</a></li>
        <li><a href="/min-dbadk/gemte-soegninger/">Gemte søgninger</a></li>
    <li><a href="/min-dbadk/mine-brugeroplysninger/" data-ga-act="mine-brugeroplysninger" data-ga-lbl="header" class="trackClicks">Mine brugeroplysninger</a></li>
    <li><a href="/min-dbadk/e-mails/" data-ga-act="administrer-emails" data-ga-lbl="header" class="trackClicks">Administrer e-mails</a></li>
    <li><a href="/min-dbadk/betalinger/" data-ga-act="blaa-konto" data-ga-lbl="header" class="trackClicks">Betalinger</a></li>
        <li><a href="/fragt/" data-ga-act="shipping-landing-page" data-ga-lbl="header" class="trackClicks">Køb pakkelabel</a></li>
<li><a href="/log-ud/" id="signout" data-ga-act="logout" data-ga-lbl="header">Log ud<small data-bind="{text:UserNameFormatted}"> (sebastian)</small></a></li></ul></div>
                </div>
                <div id="syi-create" class="dropdown-call-to-action pull-right">
                    <a href="/opret-annonce/" title="Sæt dine ting til salg her" data-ga-act="PostAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="header" id="syi-btn" class="btn btn-large btn-call-to-action trackClicks">Opret annonce</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>











    <nav class="breadcrumb">
        <ul class=" container">
            <li><a href="http://www.dba.dk" title="Nyt og brugt, køb og salg på DBA - Danmarks største handelsportal">Forside</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/min-dbadk/">Min DBA</a>
            </li>
            <li>Mine annoncer</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


    <div role="main" id="content" class="container">





<div class="top">
    <div class="chat-support clearfix">
    <div id="chatPlaceholder" class="pull-right">
        <a href="http://www.dba.dk/aspsite/support/" target="_blank" data-bind="html: liveChatText, click: handle"><span class="tag tag-online">Live!</span> Chat med support</a>
    </div>
</div>



</div>

<div class="sidebar-layout">
    <aside class="sidebar sidebar-left">

<div class="mydba-menu">
<h3>
    Min DBA <small style="display:inline-block">sebastian nielsen</small>
</h3>
<ul>

    <li class="active">
        <span>
        Mine annoncer

            <small>( 4 )</small>


    </span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="/min-dbadk/favoritter/">
            Favoritter

                <small>( 0 )</small>


        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="/min-dbadk/saelgere-jeg-foelger/">
            Sælgere du følger


        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="/min-dbadk/gemte-soegninger/">
            Gemte søgninger


        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="/min-dbadk/mine-brugeroplysninger/">
            Mine brugeroplysninger


        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="/min-dbadk/skift-adgangskode/">
            Skift adgangskode


        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="/min-dbadk/e-mails/">
            Administrer e-mails


        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="/min-dbadk/betalinger/">
            Betalinger


        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="/fragt/" data-ga-cat="MyDba" data-ga-act="shipping-landing-page" data-ga-lbl="shipping" class="trackClicks">
            Køb pakkelabel


        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
    </aside>
    <section class="content sidebar-left">

        <div class="marketing-container">
            <div id="google-dfp-marketing" class="adslot" data-adslot="{&quot;bids&quot;:null,&quot;adSlotId&quot;:&quot;google-dfp-marketing&quot;,&quot;sizes&quot;:[[700,160]],&quot;targeting&quot;:[{&quot;key&quot;:&quot;position&quot;,&quot;values&quot;:[&quot;marketing&quot;],&quot;isEmpty&quot;:false}],&quot;collapse&quot;:false}"></div>



        </div>






<div class="tabs">
    <ul>

        <li class="current">
            <div class="a">
                <span>
                    Mine annoncer

                    <small>
                        ( 4 )</small>

                </span>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/min-dbadk/mine-annoncer/aktive-annoncer/"><span>
            Kun aktive annoncer

            <small>
                ( 4 )</small>

        </span></a></li>

        <li>
            <div class="a">
                <span>
                    Kun inaktive annoncer

                    <small>
                        ( 0 )</small>

                </span>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>

<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CDVIQEr_BGF3LlXewKgXuRn5QT71jlSNckiVD5C6w5j_qqKOOgZOyiWqsef9zAv5uupa7l1Yx_c7d5fL_8bUTG7CQKxnOoMXHbLHxf5Dd5JYldvEmI4ZaSqgAw22mcTAQWtVJQ2">

    <table class="searchResults srpListView">
        <thead class="sorting">
            <tr>
                <th class="noWrap" colspan="3">Annonce</th>
                <th class="noWrap">Besøg
                </th>
                <th class="noWrap">Tid tilbage
                </th>
                <th class="noWrap">Favoritter</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


<tr class="dbaListing listing hasInsertionFee">

    <td class="pictureColumn" colspan="1">
        <div class="thumbnailContainer">
            <a class="thumbnailContainerInner" href="http://www.dba.dk/tastatur-mad-catz-strike-7/id-1029751995/">

            <img class="thumbnail lazy image-placeholder" alt="Tastatur, Mad Catz, Strike 7, Perfekt, Den er helt ny, stadig i fuld indpakning. 

Hvorfor sælger jeg?
Jeg opdagede at jeg havde skaffet det forkerte tastetur, der var ment som gave. Og siden at jeg havde ventet for længe med at få den byttet, var det altså for sent. Derfor sælger jeg den så for 1900 kr. (300 mindre en nypris)

Den er virkelig alle pengene værd, og har så mange funktioner, at jeg aldrig kan komme tæt på at beskrive alt her. Derfor hvis i er interesserede i den kan i..." data-original="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/3d/05/e060-37f5-4465-af3e-d20e730a9853.jpg?preset=srpgallery" src="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/3d/05/e060-37f5-4465-af3e-d20e730a9853.jpg?preset=srpgallery" style="display: block;">
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>

<td class="mainContent" colspan="2">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "Tastatur, Mad Catz, Strike 7, Perfekt, Den er...",
        "image": "http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/3d/05/e060-37f5-4465-af3e-d20e730a9853.jpg?preset=medium",
        "url": "http://www.dba.dk/tastatur-mad-catz-strike-7/id-1029751995/",
        "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "priceCurrency": "DKK",
            "price": "1900"
        }
    }
    </script>

    <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/tastatur-mad-catz-strike-7/id-1029751995/">
            <span class="headline-block">
                            </span>

    </a>

    <div class="expandable-box expandable-box-collapsed">
        <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/tastatur-mad-catz-strike-7/id-1029751995/">Tastatur, Mad Catz, Strike 7, Perfekt, Den er helt ny, stadig i fuld indpakning. 

Hvorfor sælger jeg?
Jeg opdagede at jeg havde skaffet det forkerte tastetur, der var ment som gave. Og siden at jeg havde ventet for længe med at få den byttet, var det altså for sent. Derfor sælger jeg den så for 1900 kr. (300 mindre en nypris)

Den er virkelig alle pengene værd, og har så mange funktioner, at jeg aldrig kan komme tæt på at beskrive alt her. Derfor hvis i er interesserede i den kan i...</a>
        <a class="link-to-listing" href="http://www.dba.dk/tastatur-mad-catz-strike-7/id-1029751995/">Se hele annoncen</a>
    </div>


<ul class="details">

    <li>


<span>1.900 kr.</span>
    </li>

</ul>

</td>




                <td>

<span>116</span></td>
                <td>

<span>10 dage</span></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>

        <div class="listingUpselling bump-up-upsell">
            <p>
                Er nu på side <b>55</b>.
            </p>
            <p><a href="/produkt-tilvalg/?id=1029751995&amp;produktId=BumpUp&amp;returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dba.dk%2Fmin-dbadk%2Fmine-annoncer%2F" rel="nofollow" data-ga-act="bumpup-upsell-page-number-click" data-ga-lbl="tenzing-project" class="upsellingButton btn btn-small trackClicks">Køb oprykning</a></p>
        </div>

</td>
<td class="noWrap myDbaActions">
    <ul class="unstyled">
            <li>
                <a href="/rediger-annonce/?id=1029751995" data-ga-act="EditAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" class="trackClicks">Rediger</a>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.inactivateListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/InActivateListing', 1029751995); return false; ">Deaktiver</a>
            </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" data-ga-act="DeleteAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.deleteListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/DeleteListing', 1029751995); return false;" class="trackClicks">Slet</a>
        </li>


            <li>
                <a href="/paypal/anmodning/?externalid=1029751995" data-ga-act="click" data-ga-lbl="paypal-request-payment" class="trackClicks">Start PayPal</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/fragt/1029751995/" data-ga-act="shipping-buy-label" data-ga-lbl="shipping" class="trackClicks">Køb pakkelabel</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</td>
                </tr>  


<tr class="dbaListing listing hasInsertionFee">

    <td class="pictureColumn" colspan="1">
        <div class="thumbnailContainer">
            <a class="thumbnailContainerInner" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-akribos-xxiv-test/id-1030155633/">

            <img class="thumbnail lazy image-placeholder" alt="Dykkerur, Akribos XXIV, test" data-original="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/41/0d/7053-631b-4ba6-b520-cb0cbdd67b29.jpg?preset=srpgallery" src="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/41/0d/7053-631b-4ba6-b520-cb0cbdd67b29.jpg?preset=srpgallery" style="display: block;">
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>

<td class="mainContent" colspan="2">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "Dykkerur, Akribos XXIV, test",
        "image": "http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/41/0d/7053-631b-4ba6-b520-cb0cbdd67b29.jpg?preset=medium",
        "url": "http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-akribos-xxiv-test/id-1030155633/",
        "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "priceCurrency": "DKK",
            "price": "9999"
        }
    }
    </script>

    <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-akribos-xxiv-test/id-1030155633/">
            <span class="headline-block">
                            </span>

    </a>

    <div class="expandable-box expandable-box-collapsed">
        <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-akribos-xxiv-test/id-1030155633/">Dykkerur, Akribos XXIV, test</a>
        <a class="link-to-listing" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-akribos-xxiv-test/id-1030155633/">Se hele annoncen</a>
    </div>


<ul class="details">

    <li>


<span>9.999 kr.</span>
    </li>

</ul>

</td>




                <td>

<span>18</span></td>
                <td>

<span>29 dage</span></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>

        <div class="listingUpselling top-listing-upsell">
            <p>
                Få din annonce på side 1 i 3 dage.
            </p>
            <p><a href="/produkt-tilvalg/?id=1030155633&amp;produktId=TopListing&amp;returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dba.dk%2Fmin-dbadk%2Fmine-annoncer%2F" rel="nofollow" data-ga-act="top-listing-upsell-click" data-ga-lbl="tenzing-project" class="upsellingButton btn btn-small trackClicks">Køb topannonce</a></p>
        </div>

</td>
<td class="noWrap myDbaActions">
    <ul class="unstyled">
            <li>
                <a href="/rediger-annonce/?id=1030155633" data-ga-act="EditAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" class="trackClicks">Rediger</a>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.inactivateListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/InActivateListing', 1030155633); return false; ">Deaktiver</a>
            </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" data-ga-act="DeleteAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.deleteListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/DeleteListing', 1030155633); return false;" class="trackClicks">Slet</a>
        </li>


            <li>
                <a href="/paypal/anmodning/?externalid=1030155633" data-ga-act="click" data-ga-lbl="paypal-request-payment" class="trackClicks">Start PayPal</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/fragt/1030155633/" data-ga-act="shipping-buy-label" data-ga-lbl="shipping" class="trackClicks">Køb pakkelabel</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</td>
                </tr>  


<tr class="dbaListing listing hasInsertionFee">

    <td class="pictureColumn" colspan="1">
        <div class="thumbnailContainer">
            <a class="thumbnailContainerInner" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-adidas-test/id-1030155766/">

            <img class="thumbnail lazy image-placeholder" alt="Dykkerur, Adidas, test" data-original="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/6d/45/bee3-8bb7-4e0b-9cb4-4c75ebea7ac2.jpg?preset=srpgallery" src="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/6d/45/bee3-8bb7-4e0b-9cb4-4c75ebea7ac2.jpg?preset=srpgallery" style="display: block;">
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>

<td class="mainContent" colspan="2">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "Dykkerur, Adidas, test",
        "image": "http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/6d/45/bee3-8bb7-4e0b-9cb4-4c75ebea7ac2.jpg?preset=medium",
        "url": "http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-adidas-test/id-1030155766/",
        "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "priceCurrency": "DKK",
            "price": "9999"
        }
    }
    </script>

    <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-adidas-test/id-1030155766/">
            <span class="headline-block">
                            </span>

    </a>

    <div class="expandable-box expandable-box-collapsed">
        <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-adidas-test/id-1030155766/">Dykkerur, Adidas, test</a>
        <a class="link-to-listing" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-adidas-test/id-1030155766/">Se hele annoncen</a>
    </div>


<ul class="details">

    <li>


<span>9.999 kr.</span>
    </li>

</ul>

</td>




                <td>

<span>14</span></td>
                <td>

<span>29 dage</span></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>

        <div class="listingUpselling top-listing-upsell">
            <p>
                Få din annonce på side 1 i 3 dage.
            </p>
            <p><a href="/produkt-tilvalg/?id=1030155766&amp;produktId=TopListing&amp;returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dba.dk%2Fmin-dbadk%2Fmine-annoncer%2F" rel="nofollow" data-ga-act="top-listing-upsell-click" data-ga-lbl="tenzing-project" class="upsellingButton btn btn-small trackClicks">Køb topannonce</a></p>
        </div>

</td>
<td class="noWrap myDbaActions">
    <ul class="unstyled">
            <li>
                <a href="/rediger-annonce/?id=1030155766" data-ga-act="EditAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" class="trackClicks">Rediger</a>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.inactivateListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/InActivateListing', 1030155766); return false; ">Deaktiver</a>
            </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" data-ga-act="DeleteAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.deleteListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/DeleteListing', 1030155766); return false;" class="trackClicks">Slet</a>
        </li>


            <li>
                <a href="/paypal/anmodning/?externalid=1030155766" data-ga-act="click" data-ga-lbl="paypal-request-payment" class="trackClicks">Start PayPal</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/fragt/1030155766/" data-ga-act="shipping-buy-label" data-ga-lbl="shipping" class="trackClicks">Køb pakkelabel</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</td>
                </tr>  


<tr class="dbaListing listing lastListing hasInsertionFee">

    <td class="pictureColumn" colspan="1">
        <div class="thumbnailContainer">
            <a class="thumbnailContainerInner" href="http://www.dba.dk/joystick-l-h-defekt-test/id-1030156328/">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example html file, at the bottom, is an entry with:

```
<tr class="dbaListing listing lastListing hasInsertionFee">
```

Your code is considering that a match, which make 4.

Comment: but .dbaListing.listing.hasInsertionFee is not equal to this: .dbaListing.listing.lastListing.hasInsertionFee

?

Comment: so how can that be?

Comment: ahh, wait I get it. every dot infront of every word is a new class. and I only claimed it should be equal to 3 classes, but here there is just added one class on. So it matches. Yeah I see. 

Thanks man :)

Comment: Exactly! It took me a while to get my head around that idea as well. Glad I could help. :)